# three prong adaptor caught on fire

Tags: receptacle

I have been using a three prong adaptor on my microwave.  The adaptor caught on fire when the microwave was not being used, though I had used it approx. 5 minutes earlier.  There's no sign of damage behind the cover plate, and a lamp works when plugged in.  The microwave plug is slightly melted along one edge, next to the old adaptor but otherwise looks OK.  What should I check before just plugging back in with a new adaptor?

Comment: By "three prong adapter" do you mean ["cheater plug"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheater_plug)? If so, did you leave the appliance ground unconnected?

Comment: The 3 way adapters are almost always molded and can be easily overloaded. This combined with loose fitting sockets is probably why it melted. A plug strip would be a safer way to have multiple outlets IMO.

Comment: I do mean "cheater plug," the kind with a wire, which was not connected.  The house is old and I do not believe this wire would result in a true ground but I will connect wire or tab in the future.  After reading answer from Carl Witthoft I believe the adaptor plug had worked loose from the outlet, which I did unscrew from the box to examine behind the wall.  Should I be looking to replace the microwave cord with a pigtail or just try to replace the plug itself?  Is the latter even possible?

Comment: If the cord and plug have any damage, then yes, you should replace them. You can find replacement plugs in the electrical aisle at your hardware store.

Comment: Make sure to buy the $3 variety and not the 80 cent cheapies.  Also do not install a grounded (3-pin) outlet unless it's a $20 GFCI outlet, which is an elegant, professonal and legal solution, as Grant discusses.

Answer (score 3):

The proper solution is to replace the outlet with a 3 prong GFCI one, and label it "No Equipment Ground".

You are allowed to replace an ungrounded outlet with a GFCI.

Then just plug your microwave in.

Or run new wire and ground it properly, but that is a much bigger job.

Comment: I agree this is the proper solution.  Since the male plug on the microwave is likely damage by heat internally I would suggest cutting it off and replacing it with a nice 90degree [cord cap](http://m.lowes.com/pd/Cooper-Wiring-Devices-15-Amp-125-Volt-White-3-Wire-Plug/3568876) that will not get strained because the microwave is being pushed back.  (The link shows white, I don't think I've ever actually seen a white one, there usually black but I couldn't find that one.) replacing both plug and receptacle is really the best solution, and the receptacle must be GFCI

Answer (score 2):

This is not the fault of the adapter: if you'd shorted the ground wire to hot (for example), a fuse would have blown.

It's almost certain that you did not plug the microwave firmly into the adapter, or the adapter firmly into the socket.  As a result, there was a weak connection inside the adapter, leading to either significant ohmic load or local arcing, either of which lead to meltdown and burning due to running the microwave.

Kill the fuse/breaker and inspect the wall socket for signs of damage or carbon buildup in the slots.  Clean or replace as necessary.  Replace damaged adapter and damaged plug on microwave wiring.

Answer (score 1):

The ground issue is a red herring.

The issue is that one of the sockets (probably the one in the cheater) is not clamping the plug blades very well. Either it is cheap junk, or lost its "spring".  As it started to heat up, it lost more spring - vicious cycle.

Current was flowing, but only by arcing inside the cheater, and microwaves take a lot of current -- hence a lot of arcing, and the fire.

The answer is search your house for any loosey-goosey or sloppy-doppy outlet connections, and replace with quality outlets that hold their grip.

There's no such thing as a quality cheater, and there never will be, because the problem is elegantly solved by GFCI's -- as aptly described by Grant in his answer.

Grounds are important and you shouldn't use cheaters without proper grounding (and really, ever, now that the GFCI solution exists).  But that's not what caused this.